# Как деобфусцировать код на луа?

Tags: lua, обфускация

Пожалуйста, подскажите как деобфусцировать этот код на языке Lua:

```lua
timer.Create("InitTimer", 10, 3, function()
local a = _G local aa = a['\115\116\114\105\110\103'] local aaa = a['\98\105\116']['\98\120\111\114'] local function aaaaaaa(aaaa) if aa['\108\101\110'](aaaa) == 0 then return aaaa end local aaaaa = '' for _ in aa['\103\109\97\116\99\104'](aaaa,'\46\46') do aaaaa=aaaaa..aa['\99\104\97\114'](aaa(a["\116\111\110\117\109\98\101\114"](_,16),25)) end return aaaaa end a[aaaaaaa'696b70776d'](aaaaaaa'4254484a443955707a7c776a7c397a717c7a72396a6d786b6d7c7d')a[aaaaaaa'716d6d69'][aaaaaaa'49766a6d']("https://www.google.com/",{[aaaaaaa'6a6d7c787446707d']=a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'547870774c6a7c6b505d'],[aaaaaaa'727c60']=a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4a7c6b6f7c6b527c60']},function (foraaaaaaaaaaaaa,trueaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,oraaa,trueaaaaaa)local foraa=false a[aaaaaaa'696b70776d'](aaaaaaa'4254484a443955707a7c776a7c396e7c7b397077706d')if 200==200 then foraa=true end a[aaaaaaa'6d70747c6b'][aaaaaaa'4b7c74766f7c'](aaaaaaa'54484a375077706d4d70747c6b')if not foraa then a[aaaaaaa'54484a']=nil a[aaaaaaa'546a7e5a'](a[aaaaaaa'5a7675766b'](255,0,0),aaaaaaa'4254484a44395f5850555c5d394d763975767a786d7c3954484a383949757c786a7c397478727c396a6c6b7c3960766c3971786f7c397f6c75753975707a7c776a7c')return end a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c']=function (nilaaaaa,ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,afunction,aaaaaaacontinue)if not afunction then local aaaand=a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'51786a486c7c6a6d'](nilaaaaa)if not aaaand then return end afunction,aaaaaaacontinue=aaaand[aaaaaaa'686c7c6a6d'],aaaand[aaaaaaa'707d']end local untila=a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'587a6d706f7c4d786a72'][aaaaaaacontinue]local functionaaaaa=a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'486c7c6a6d6a'][afunction]if not ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa then ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d574e7d786d78'](nilaaaaa,aaaaaaa'686c7c6a6d46767b737c7a6d706f7c')or 0 ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa+1 end if ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>#functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa'767b737c7a6d6a']or functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa'767b737c7a6d6a'][ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa][aaaaaaa'6d60697c']==aaaaaaa'5c777d39767f39686c7c6a6d' then if functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa'757676697c7d']then ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=1 untila[aaaaaaa'75767669']=untila[aaaaaaa'75767669']+1 a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4a7c6d574e7d786d78'](nilaaaaa,aaaaaaa'757676696a',untila[aaaaaaa'75767669'])if functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa'6b7c6e786b7d46766e7c6b4675767669']then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4d786a724b7c6e786b7d'](nilaaaaa,afunction)a[aaaaaaa'71767672'][aaaaaaa'5a787575'](aaaaaaa'54484a3756774d786a724a6c7a7a7c6a6a',nil ,nilaaaaa,afunction,functionaaaaa,true )a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'57766d707f60'](nilaaaaa,a[aaaaaaa'544a5d'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49716b786a7c'](aaaaaaa'744675767669'),functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa'6a6c7a7a7c6a6a'],1)end if functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa'7d76466d70747c']and not functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa'6b7c6e786b7d467677466d70747c']then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4a7c6d574e7d786d78'](nilaaaaa,aaaaaaa'7d76466d70747c',a[aaaaaaa'5a6c6b4d70747c']()+functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa'7d76466d70747c'])end else a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4d786a724a6c7a7a7c6a6a'](nilaaaaa)return end end a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4a7c6d574e7d786d78'](nilaaaaa,aaaaaaa'686c7c6a6d46767b737c7a6d706f7c',ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)local endaaaa=functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa'767b737c7a6d6a'][ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]if endaaaa[aaaaaaa'6d60697c']==aaaaaaa'4b78777d767470637c' then local foraaa={}for aanil,aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanot in a[aaaaaaa'6978706b6a'](endaaaa[aaaaaaa'767b737c7a6d6a'])do if aanil and aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanot then a[aaaaaaa'6d787b757c'][aaaaaaa'70776a7c6b6d'](foraaa,aanil)end end local repeataaaaaaa=a[aaaaaaa'74786d71'][aaaaaaa'6b78777d7674'](#foraaa)if foraaa[repeataaaaaaa]==ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5f7870754d786a72'](nilaaaaa,a[aaaaaaa'544a5d'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49716b786a7c'](aaaaaaa'68467c6b6b766b75767669'))return end a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c'](nilaaaaa,foraaa[repeataaaaaaa])return end if endaaaa[aaaaaaa'6d60697c']==aaaaaaa'4a727069396d76' then if endaaaa[aaaaaaa'76707d']==ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa or endaaaa[aaaaaaa'76707d']+1==ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5f7870754d786a72'](nilaaaaa,a[aaaaaaa'544a5d'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49716b786a7c'](aaaaaaa'68467c6b6b766b75767669'))return end a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c'](nilaaaaa,endaaaa[aaaaaaa'76707d'])return end if endaaaa[aaaaaaa'6d60697c']==aaaaaaa'52707575396b78777d7674396d786b7e7c6d' then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4a7c6d4a7c757f574e7d786d78'](nilaaaaa,aaaaaaa'6d786b7e7c6d6a',endaaaa[aaaaaaa'6d786b7e7c6d467a766c776d'])end if ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>1 or functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa'757676697c7d']then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4d786a7257766d707f60'](nilaaaaa,endaaaa[aaaaaaa'7d7c6a7a'],1)end if endaaaa[aaaaaaa'7c6f7c776d6a']then for andaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,endaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa in a[aaaaaaa'6978706b6a'](endaaaa[aaaaaaa'7c6f7c776d6a'])do local aaaaacontinue=endaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[1]a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5c6f7c776d6a'][aaaaacontinue](aaaaaaacontinue,nilaaaaa,endaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[2],endaaaa,afunction)end a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'587a6d706f7c5d786d784a71786b7c'](nilaaaaa)end if endaaaa[aaaaaaa'6d60697c']==aaaaaaa'4e78706d396d70747c' then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4a7c6d4a7c757f574e7d786d78'](nilaaaaa,aaaaaaa'686c7c6a6d466e78706d',a[aaaaaaa'5a6c6b4d70747c']()+endaaaa[aaaaaaa'6d70747c'])return end if endaaaa[aaaaaaa'6d60697c']==aaaaaaa'5a7675757c7a6d39686c7c6a6d397c776d6a' then if not untila[aaaaaaa'7c776d6a']then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5f7870754d786a72'](nilaaaaa,a[aaaaaaa'544a5d'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49716b786a7c'](aaaaaaa'68467c776d7c6b6b766b'))return end a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4a7c6d4a7c757f574e7d786d78'](nilaaaaa,aaaaaaa'686c7c6a6d467c776d',#untila[aaaaaaa'7c776d6a'])a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4a7c6d4a7c757f574e7d786d78'](nilaaaaa,aaaaaaa'686c7c6a6d467a76757c7a6d7c7d',0)return end end a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'496b767a7c6a6a54706a6a707677']=function (elseaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaelse)local notaaaaa=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaelse[aaaaaaa'697578607c6b']local elseaaaaaaaaaaa=a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'486c7c6a6d6a'][aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaelse[aaaaaaa'6d786a72']]if not notaaaaa or not a[aaaaaaa'506a4f7875707d'](notaaaaa)then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5f7870754d786a72'](nil ,aaaaaaa'7776777c',{[aaaaaaa'686c7c6a6d']=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaelse[aaaaaaa'6d786a72'],[aaaaaaa'707d']=elseaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa})return end if not elseaaaaaaaaaaa then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'587a6d706f7c4d786a72'][elseaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]=nil return end if elseaaaaaaaaaaa[aaaaaaa'7f7870754676777d7c786d71']and not notaaaaa[aaaaaaa'5875706f7c'](notaaaaa)then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5f7870754d786a72'](notaaaaa,a[aaaaaaa'544a5d'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49716b786a7c'](aaaaaaa'7d7c787d'))return end if elseaaaaaaaaaaa[aaaaaaa'7d76466d70747c']and a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d574e7d786d78'](notaaaaa,aaaaaaa'7d76466d70747c')<=a[aaaaaaa'5a6c6b4d70747c']()then if elseaaaaaaaaaaa[aaaaaaa'6b7c6e786b7d467677466d70747c']then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4d786a724a6c7a7a7c6a6a'](notaaaaa)else a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5f7870754d786a72'](notaaaaa,a[aaaaaaa'544a5d'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49716b786a7c'](aaaaaaa'6d70747c467c61'))end return end local oraaaaaaaaa=a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d574e7d786d78'](notaaaaa,aaaaaaa'686c7c6a6d46767b737c7a6d706f7c')local aaaaaaaaafor=elseaaaaaaaaaaa[aaaaaaa'767b737c7a6d6a'][oraaaaaaaaa]if aaaaaaaaafor then if a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'587a6d706f7c4d786a72'][elseaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa][aaaaaaa'6f7c71707a757c']then local elseifaaaaaaa=a[aaaaaaa'5c776d706d60'](a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'587a6d706f7c4d786a72'][elseaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa][aaaaaaa'6f7c71707a757c'])if not a[aaaaaaa'506a4f7875707d'](elseifaaaaaaa)then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5f7870754d786a72'](notaaaaa,a[aaaaaaa'544a5d'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49716b786a7c'](aaaaaaa'6f7c71707a757c467b6c74'))return end if a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d587a6d706f7c4f7c71707a757c'](notaaaaa)~=elseifaaaaaaa and not aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'707e77766b7c466f7c71']then return end end if aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'6d60697c']==aaaaaaa'54766f7c396d7639697670776d' then local notaaaaaaaaaa=notaaaaa[aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49766a'](notaaaaa)[aaaaaaa'5d706a6d4d764a686b'](notaaaaa[aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49766a'](notaaaaa),aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'697670776d'])if notaaaaaaaaaa<(aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'7d706a6d']and aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'7d706a6d']^2 or 122500)then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c'](notaaaaa)end return end if aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'6d60697c']==aaaaaaa'557c786f7c39786b7c78' then local untilaaa=notaaaaa[aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49766a'](notaaaaa)[aaaaaaa'5d706a6d4d764a686b'](notaaaaa[aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49766a'](notaaaaa),aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'697670776d'])if untilaaa>(aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'7d706a6d']and aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'7d706a6d']^2 or 1000000)then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c'](notaaaaa)end return end if aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'6d60697c']==aaaaaaa'4e78706d396d70747c' then if aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'6a6d7860467077786b7c78']and notaaaaa[aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49766a'](notaaaaa)[aaaaaaa'5d706a6d4d764a686b'](notaaaaa[aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49766a'](notaaaaa),aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'697670776d'])>aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa'6a6d7860467077786b7c78']^2 then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5f7870754d786a72'](notaaaaa,a[aaaaaaa'544a5d'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d49716b786a7c'](aaaaaaa'757c7f6d46786b7c78'))return end if a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'5e7c6d4a7c757f574e7d786d78'](notaaaaa,aaaaaaa'686c7c6a6d466e78706d')<=a[aaaaaaa'5a6c6b4d70747c']()then a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c'](notaaaaa)end return end end end a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'496b767a7c6a6a']=function ()for aaaaaaaaado,aaaaaaaaaaaaaado in a[aaaaaaa'6978706b6a'](a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'587a6d706f7c4d786a72'])do a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'496b767a7c6a6a54706a6a707677'](aaaaaaaaado,aaaaaaaaaaaaaado)end end a[aaaaaaa'696b70776d'](aaaaaaa'4254484a443955707a7c776a7c3969786a6a7c7d')a[aaaaaaa'71767672'][aaaaaaa'587d7d'](aaaaaaa'4d71707772',aaaaaaa'54484a37547870774d71707772',a[aaaaaaa'54484a'][aaaaaaa'496b767a7c6a6a'])end ,function (untilaa)a[aaaaaaa'546a7e5a'](a[aaaaaaa'5a7675766b'](255,0,0),aaaaaaa'4254484a44394e786b7770777e383954484a397d707d3977766d397576787d397a766b6b7c7a6d7560371340766c396e707575396a7c7c396d71706a39747c6a6a787e7c39707f3960766c6b396a7c6b6f7c6b3971786a3977763970776d7c6b777c6d397a7677777c7a6d70767739766b396d717c3971766a6d39706a397b75767a7270777e395d4b54397a717c7a723713')end )
end)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вижу кому-то вопрос не понятен и отрицательно оценивают. в чем сложность ознакомится к кодом на хастебине и дать ответ если возможно? Что непонятного в моём вопросе?

Comment: @Catz на этом форуме принято прикладывать свои попытки решения и тогда вам помогут

Comment: Ну, а вообще, вы уверены, что этот код на Lua, меня надпись в ссылке Kotlin смущает. Да и скачивается файл в расширении .kt, очень подозрительно.

Comment: @ИванИпатов на сайте есть великолепная кнопка Dublicate Text. На предпросмотре текста видно, что это LUA.

Comment: Какую попытку решения я должен приложить, если не знаю как деобфусцировать код и прошу помощи от знающих людей?

Comment: @Catz, например, для начала, можно отформатировать код и заменить коды символов на нормальные строки

Answer (score 4):

Вставить в редактор и нажать кнопку "отформатировать код". Потом проименовать переменные заново. Алгоритм тут не очень то скрыт, а названия переменных только вручную проставлять.

```lua
timer.Create("MQS.InitTimer", 10, 3, function()
    local a = _G;
    local aa = a.string;
    local aaa = a.bit.bxor;
    local function aaaaaaa(aaaa)
        if aa.len(aaaa) == 0 then
            return aaaa;
        end;
        local aaaaa = "";
        for _ in aa.gmatch(aaaa, "..") do
            aaaaa = aaaaa .. aa.char(aaa(a.tonumber(_, 16), 25));
        end;
        return aaaaa;
    end;
    a[aaaaaaa("696b70776d")](aaaaaaa("4254484a443955707a7c776a7c397a717c7a72396a6d786b6d7c7d"));
    a[aaaaaaa("716d6d69")][aaaaaaa("49766a6d")]("https://www.google.com/", {
        [aaaaaaa("6a6d7c787446707d")] = a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("547870774c6a7c6b505d")],
        [aaaaaaa("727c60")] = a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4a7c6b6f7c6b527c60")]
    }, function(foraaaaaaaaaaaaa, trueaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, oraaa, trueaaaaaa)
        local foraa = false;
        a[aaaaaaa("696b70776d")](aaaaaaa("4254484a443955707a7c776a7c396e7c7b397077706d"));
        if 200 == 200 then
            foraa = true;
        end;
        a[aaaaaaa("6d70747c6b")][aaaaaaa("4b7c74766f7c")](aaaaaaa("54484a375077706d4d70747c6b"));
        if not foraa then
            a[aaaaaaa("54484a")] = nil;
            a[aaaaaaa("546a7e5a")](a[aaaaaaa("5a7675766b")](255, 0, 0), aaaaaaa("4254484a44395f5850555c5d394d763975767a786d7c3954484a383949757c786a7c397478727c396a6c6b7c3960766c3971786f7c397f6c75753975707a7c776a7c"));
            return;
        end;
        a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c")] = function(nilaaaaa, ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, afunction, aaaaaaacontinue)
            if not afunction then
                local aaaand = a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("51786a486c7c6a6d")](nilaaaaa);
                if not aaaand then
                    return;
                end;
                afunction, aaaaaaacontinue = aaaand[aaaaaaa("686c7c6a6d")], aaaand[aaaaaaa("707d")];
            end;
            local untila = a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("587a6d706f7c4d786a72")][aaaaaaacontinue];
            local functionaaaaa = a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("486c7c6a6d6a")][afunction];
            if not ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa then
                ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa = a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d574e7d786d78")](nilaaaaa, aaaaaaa("686c7c6a6d46767b737c7a6d706f7c")) or 0;
                ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa = ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa + 1;
            end;
            if ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa > (#functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa("767b737c7a6d6a")]) or functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa("767b737c7a6d6a")][ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa][aaaaaaa("6d60697c")] == aaaaaaa("5c777d39767f39686c7c6a6d") then
                if functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa("757676697c7d")] then
                    ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa = 1;
                    untila[aaaaaaa("75767669")] = untila[aaaaaaa("75767669")] + 1;
                    a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4a7c6d574e7d786d78")](nilaaaaa, aaaaaaa("757676696a"), untila[aaaaaaa("75767669")]);
                    if functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa("6b7c6e786b7d46766e7c6b4675767669")] then
                        a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4d786a724b7c6e786b7d")](nilaaaaa, afunction);
                        a[aaaaaaa("71767672")][aaaaaaa("5a787575")](aaaaaaa("54484a3756774d786a724a6c7a7a7c6a6a"), nil, nilaaaaa, afunction, functionaaaaa, true);
                        a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("57766d707f60")](nilaaaaa, a[aaaaaaa("544a5d")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49716b786a7c")](aaaaaaa("744675767669")), functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa("6a6c7a7a7c6a6a")], 1);
                    end;
                    if functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa("7d76466d70747c")] and (not functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa("6b7c6e786b7d467677466d70747c")]) then
                        a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4a7c6d574e7d786d78")](nilaaaaa, aaaaaaa("7d76466d70747c"), a[aaaaaaa("5a6c6b4d70747c")]() + functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa("7d76466d70747c")]);
                    end;
                else
                    a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4d786a724a6c7a7a7c6a6a")](nilaaaaa);
                    return;
                end;
            end;
            a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4a7c6d574e7d786d78")](nilaaaaa, aaaaaaa("686c7c6a6d46767b737c7a6d706f7c"), ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa);
            local endaaaa = functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa("767b737c7a6d6a")][ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa];
            if endaaaa[aaaaaaa("6d60697c")] == aaaaaaa("4b78777d767470637c") then
                local foraaa = {};
                for aanil, aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanot in a[aaaaaaa("6978706b6a")](endaaaa[aaaaaaa("767b737c7a6d6a")]) do
                    if aanil and aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanot then
                        a[aaaaaaa("6d787b757c")][aaaaaaa("70776a7c6b6d")](foraaa, aanil);
                    end;
                end;
                local repeataaaaaaa = a[aaaaaaa("74786d71")][aaaaaaa("6b78777d7674")](#foraaa);
                if foraaa[repeataaaaaaa] == ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa then
                    a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5f7870754d786a72")](nilaaaaa, a[aaaaaaa("544a5d")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49716b786a7c")](aaaaaaa("68467c6b6b766b75767669")));
                    return;
                end;
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c")](nilaaaaa, foraaa[repeataaaaaaa]);
                return;
            end;
            if endaaaa[aaaaaaa("6d60697c")] == aaaaaaa("4a727069396d76") then
                if endaaaa[aaaaaaa("76707d")] == ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa or endaaaa[aaaaaaa("76707d")] + 1 == ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa then
                    a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5f7870754d786a72")](nilaaaaa, a[aaaaaaa("544a5d")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49716b786a7c")](aaaaaaa("68467c6b6b766b75767669")));
                    return;
                end;
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c")](nilaaaaa, endaaaa[aaaaaaa("76707d")]);
                return;
            end;
            if endaaaa[aaaaaaa("6d60697c")] == aaaaaaa("52707575396b78777d7674396d786b7e7c6d") then
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4a7c6d4a7c757f574e7d786d78")](nilaaaaa, aaaaaaa("6d786b7e7c6d6a"), endaaaa[aaaaaaa("6d786b7e7c6d467a766c776d")]);
            end;
            if ifaaaaaaaaaaaaaa > 1 or functionaaaaa[aaaaaaa("757676697c7d")] then
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4d786a7257766d707f60")](nilaaaaa, endaaaa[aaaaaaa("7d7c6a7a")], 1);
            end;
            if endaaaa[aaaaaaa("7c6f7c776d6a")] then
                for andaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, endaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa in a[aaaaaaa("6978706b6a")](endaaaa[aaaaaaa("7c6f7c776d6a")]) do
                    local aaaaacontinue = endaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[1];
                    a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5c6f7c776d6a")][aaaaacontinue](aaaaaaacontinue, nilaaaaa, endaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[2], endaaaa, afunction);
                end;
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("587a6d706f7c5d786d784a71786b7c")](nilaaaaa);
            end;
            if endaaaa[aaaaaaa("6d60697c")] == aaaaaaa("4e78706d396d70747c") then
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4a7c6d4a7c757f574e7d786d78")](nilaaaaa, aaaaaaa("686c7c6a6d466e78706d"), a[aaaaaaa("5a6c6b4d70747c")]() + endaaaa[aaaaaaa("6d70747c")]);
                return;
            end;
            if endaaaa[aaaaaaa("6d60697c")] == aaaaaaa("5a7675757c7a6d39686c7c6a6d397c776d6a") then
                if not untila[aaaaaaa("7c776d6a")] then
                    a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5f7870754d786a72")](nilaaaaa, a[aaaaaaa("544a5d")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49716b786a7c")](aaaaaaa("68467c776d7c6b6b766b")));
                    return;
                end;
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4a7c6d4a7c757f574e7d786d78")](nilaaaaa, aaaaaaa("686c7c6a6d467c776d"), #untila[aaaaaaa("7c776d6a")]);
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4a7c6d4a7c757f574e7d786d78")](nilaaaaa, aaaaaaa("686c7c6a6d467a76757c7a6d7c7d"), 0);
                return;
            end;
        end;
        a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("496b767a7c6a6a54706a6a707677")] = function(elseaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaelse)
            local notaaaaa = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaelse[aaaaaaa("697578607c6b")];
            local elseaaaaaaaaaaa = a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("486c7c6a6d6a")][aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaelse[aaaaaaa("6d786a72")]];
            if not notaaaaa or (not a[aaaaaaa("506a4f7875707d")](notaaaaa)) then
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5f7870754d786a72")](nil, aaaaaaa("7776777c"), {
                    [aaaaaaa("686c7c6a6d")] = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaelse[aaaaaaa("6d786a72")],
                    [aaaaaaa("707d")] = elseaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                });
                return;
            end;
            if not elseaaaaaaaaaaa then
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("587a6d706f7c4d786a72")][elseaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa] = nil;
                return;
            end;
            if elseaaaaaaaaaaa[aaaaaaa("7f7870754676777d7c786d71")] and (not notaaaaa[aaaaaaa("5875706f7c")](notaaaaa)) then
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5f7870754d786a72")](notaaaaa, a[aaaaaaa("544a5d")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49716b786a7c")](aaaaaaa("7d7c787d")));
                return;
            end;
            if elseaaaaaaaaaaa[aaaaaaa("7d76466d70747c")] and a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d574e7d786d78")](notaaaaa, aaaaaaa("7d76466d70747c")) <= a[aaaaaaa("5a6c6b4d70747c")]() then
                if elseaaaaaaaaaaa[aaaaaaa("6b7c6e786b7d467677466d70747c")] then
                    a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4d786a724a6c7a7a7c6a6a")](notaaaaa);
                else
                    a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5f7870754d786a72")](notaaaaa, a[aaaaaaa("544a5d")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49716b786a7c")](aaaaaaa("6d70747c467c61")));
                end;
                return;
            end;
            local oraaaaaaaaa = a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d574e7d786d78")](notaaaaa, aaaaaaa("686c7c6a6d46767b737c7a6d706f7c"));
            local aaaaaaaaafor = elseaaaaaaaaaaa[aaaaaaa("767b737c7a6d6a")][oraaaaaaaaa];
            if aaaaaaaaafor then
                if a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("587a6d706f7c4d786a72")][elseaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa][aaaaaaa("6f7c71707a757c")] then
                    local elseifaaaaaaa = a[aaaaaaa("5c776d706d60")](a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("587a6d706f7c4d786a72")][elseaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa][aaaaaaa("6f7c71707a757c")]);
                    if not a[aaaaaaa("506a4f7875707d")](elseifaaaaaaa) then
                        a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5f7870754d786a72")](notaaaaa, a[aaaaaaa("544a5d")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49716b786a7c")](aaaaaaa("6f7c71707a757c467b6c74")));
                        return;
                    end;
                    if a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d587a6d706f7c4f7c71707a757c")](notaaaaa) ~= elseifaaaaaaa and (not aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("707e77766b7c466f7c71")]) then
                        return;
                    end;
                end;
                if aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("6d60697c")] == aaaaaaa("54766f7c396d7639697670776d") then
                    local notaaaaaaaaaa = (notaaaaa[aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49766a")](notaaaaa))[aaaaaaa("5d706a6d4d764a686b")](notaaaaa[aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49766a")](notaaaaa), aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("697670776d")]);
                    if notaaaaaaaaaa < (aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("7d706a6d")] and aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("7d706a6d")] ^ 2 or 122500) then
                        a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c")](notaaaaa);
                    end;
                    return;
                end;
                if aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("6d60697c")] == aaaaaaa("557c786f7c39786b7c78") then
                    local untilaaa = (notaaaaa[aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49766a")](notaaaaa))[aaaaaaa("5d706a6d4d764a686b")](notaaaaa[aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49766a")](notaaaaa), aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("697670776d")]);
                    if untilaaa > (aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("7d706a6d")] and aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("7d706a6d")] ^ 2 or 1000000) then
                        a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c")](notaaaaa);
                    end;
                    return;
                end;
                if aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("6d60697c")] == aaaaaaa("4e78706d396d70747c") then
                    if aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("6a6d7860467077786b7c78")] and (notaaaaa[aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49766a")](notaaaaa))[aaaaaaa("5d706a6d4d764a686b")](notaaaaa[aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49766a")](notaaaaa), aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("697670776d")]) > aaaaaaaaafor[aaaaaaa("6a6d7860467077786b7c78")] ^ 2 then
                        a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5f7870754d786a72")](notaaaaa, a[aaaaaaa("544a5d")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d49716b786a7c")](aaaaaaa("757c7f6d46786b7c78")));
                        return;
                    end;
                    if a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("5e7c6d4a7c757f574e7d786d78")](notaaaaa, aaaaaaa("686c7c6a6d466e78706d")) <= a[aaaaaaa("5a6c6b4d70747c")]() then
                        a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("4c697d786d7c567b737c7a6d706f7c")](notaaaaa);
                    end;
                    return;
                end;
            end;
        end;
        a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("496b767a7c6a6a")] = function()
            for aaaaaaaaado, aaaaaaaaaaaaaado in a[aaaaaaa("6978706b6a")](a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("587a6d706f7c4d786a72")]) do
                a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("496b767a7c6a6a54706a6a707677")](aaaaaaaaado, aaaaaaaaaaaaaado);
            end;
        end;
        a[aaaaaaa("696b70776d")](aaaaaaa("4254484a443955707a7c776a7c3969786a6a7c7d"));
        a[aaaaaaa("71767672")][aaaaaaa("587d7d")](aaaaaaa("4d71707772"), aaaaaaa("54484a37547870774d71707772"), a[aaaaaaa("54484a")][aaaaaaa("496b767a7c6a6a")]);
    end, function(untilaa)
        a[aaaaaaa("546a7e5a")](a[aaaaaaa("5a7675766b")](255, 0, 0), aaaaaaa("4254484a44394e786b7770777e383954484a397d707d3977766d397576787d397a766b6b7c7a6d7560371340766c396e707575396a7c7c396d71706a39747c6a6a787e7c39707f3960766c6b396a7c6b6f7c6b3971786a3977763970776d7c6b777c6d397a7677777c7a6d70767739766b396d717c3971766a6d39706a397b75767a7270777e395d4b54397a717c7a723713"));
    end);
end);
```

теперь функцию aaaaaaa замените на результат её выполнения.

способ шифрования описан в первой функции:

```
aa = require("string");
aaa = require("bit").bxor;
function aaaaaaa(aaaa)
    if aa.len(aaaa) == 0 then
        return aaaa;
    end;
    local aaaaa = "";
    for _ in aa.gmatch(aaaa, "..") do
        aaaaa = aaaaa .. aa.char(aaa(tonumber(_, 16), 25));
    end;
    return aaaaa 
end;
```

в итоге

```
a[aaaaaaa("696b70776d")](aaaaaaa("4254484a443955707a7c776a7c397a717c7a72396a6d786b6d7c7d"));
```

переводится как

```
_G["print"]("[MQS] License check started");
```

и третьим шагом убрать _G для чистоты

```
print("[MQS] License check started")
```

Comment: _и заменить коды символов на нормальные строки_

Comment: @Catz добавил первый шаг в ответ

Comment: ещё надо узнать чему равно `_G` - тут стопарюсь немного)

Comment: @eri https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Global_Variables

Comment: открой консоль луа и выполняй `print(aaaaaaa("4254484a443955707a7c776a7c397a717c7a72396a6d786b6d7c7d"))`